# How to get the url of a file on Google Drive using its ID with Python

Tags: python, pandas, url, google-drive-api

In the code below I get the fileID of a csv file on Google Drive. Now, I want to store the file content directly in a pandas frame instead of downloading the csv file and afterwards extracting the data (as shown in the code).

```
import io
import os.path
import pandas as pd

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload


# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']

# Login to Google Drive
def login():

    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        print ("Login to your to your Google Drive account which holds/shares the file database")
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                './src/credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    # Return service
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    
    return service


# Download files from Google Drive
def downloadFile(file_name):

    # Authenticate
    service = login()

    # Search file by name
    response = service.files().list(q=f"name='{file_name}'", spaces='drive', fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)').execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        file_id = file.get('id')

    # Download file file if it exists
    if ("file_id" in locals()):
        request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
        fh = io.FileIO(f"./data/{file_name}.csv", "wb")
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
        print (f"Downloading {file_name}.csv")
    else:
        print (f"\033[1;31m Warning: Can't download >> {file_name} << because it is missing!!!\033[0;0m")

    return


downloadFile("NameOfFile")
```

Is there any way to achieve this?
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your situation and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `The problem is to be able to do that I need the file's URL but I'm not able to retrieve it.`, I thought that your file might be Google Spreadsheet. When the file is Google Spreadsheet, `webContentLink` is not included in the retrieved metadata.

If my understanding of your situation is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```py
file_id = file.get('id')

# !!! Here, I would like to get the URL of the file and download it to a pandas data frame !!!
file_url = file.get("webContentLink")
```

##### To:

```py
file_id = file.get('id')
file_url = file.get("webContentLink")
if not file_url:
    request = service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType='text/csv')
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print("Download %d%%" % int(status.progress() * 100))
    fh.seek(0)
    df = pd.read_csv(fh)
    print(df)
```

- In this modification, the Google Spreadsheet is exported as the CSV data using Drive API, and the exported data is put to the dataframe.
- In this modification, please add `import io` and `from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload`.

#### Note:

- In this case, the Google Spreadsheet is exported as the CSV data using Drive API. So please include the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`. When your scope is only `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly`, an error occurs. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)

### Added:

When the file is the CSV data, please modify as follows.

```py
file_id = file.get('id')
request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print("Download %d%%" % int(status.progress() * 100))
fh.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(fh)
print(df)
```

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately, It always gives me an error when executing your code proposal saying "pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file". I will update my question so it becomes more precise.

Comment: I solved the issue. A csv file can't be downloaded using "export_media". Instead "get_media" has to be used then your code works like a charm. Can you please update it so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: @pa1ric6 Thank you for replying. I added a modified script for the case that the file is the CSV data. Could you please confirm it? When `io.FileIO` is used, the downloaded file is saved as a file. When `io.BytesIO()` is used, the CSV data can be put into the dataframe without creating the file.

Comment: The modified script works perfectly. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @pa1ric6 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.